# i hv tried opening a soccer game i hv just downloaded

Tags: htc-one

Every time I open it ,it loads then just crushes and goes back to the home screen. I have  tried to reinstall it but all in vain I have tried to clear all the background apps but still no sign of improvement. The game is Winner Eleven Elite by Touch Tao.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the game doesn't support your device. If you have any other devices, try to open the game, and if it still doesn't, then try contacting the developer of the game.

Comment: There has been a recent lagging of the phone .can that be the prob